# extjs. How to change dataformat for Ext.field.DatePicker

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

my post requires is fallen, cause DB need yyyy-mm-dd format. 
But datepickerfield has mm-dd-yyyy.
format config doesn't work:

```
..,{

        xtype: 'datepickerfield',
        destroyPickerOnHide: true,
        format: 'Y-m-d', 
        value: new Date(),
        label: 'Start date',
        name: 'use_start'
    },..
```

How to change dataformat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is to convert you'r date before sending it like this :

```
Ext.Date.format(DATE_VAR, DATE_FORMAT);
```

List of format : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.Date.html

Another solution is to override the default date like this into you'r application constructor :

```
Ext.apply(Ext.util.Format, {
    defaultDateFormat: DATE_FORMAT
})
```

Comment: I added 
    launch : function () {
     Ext.util.Format.defaultDateFormat= 'Y-m-d';
    } into app.js , it havn't been positive result

Comment: Now it is work! Second  solution. Thank you for a suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Well after using of Enzo's suggest data format in Ext JS had corrected. But request stays failure. It was fixed by changing DataField model Django  to DataTimeField. Check your backends too, if you face with problem like that.